# sed to insert a html values in a specific line number

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, html

I was trying to insert a values in between html tags in a specific line number. Also it should ignore whitespaces at the beginning.
Example :- line 15 should be replaced

```
<john></john>
```

this should be replaced with:

```
<john>hello</john>
```

Comment: Can you give input examples and desired outputs?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: sed is bad tool for parsing html documents. Post the extended html markup to show the adjacent context lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use simple `s///` pattern:

```
echo "<john></john>" | sed 's/<john><\/john>/<john>hello<\/john>/'
```

Output will be:

```
<john>hello</john>
```

To **replace certain line** in file use this command:

```
sed '15s/<john><\/john>/<john>hello<\/john>/' file
```

`sed` will replace only first occurance in 15 line

To simplify your command you could use `|` as delimeter instead of default `/`:

```
sed '15s|<john></john>|<john>hello</john>|' file
```

Comment: If it as simple as written by the OP then `sed '15s/></>hello</'
`

Comment: @bu5hman, yes, you are right. But what if this line contains other tags?..

Comment: The OP question pertains to a single set of tags on a known line so it works  and I could equally ask you ".....what if the tags aren't John...."? We are both correct but the key point to take away is that the OP must identify the **unique** delimiters in any given case.